# How to write node js code in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I want to generate json schema from json object. I found the tool to generate json schema from json object which is written in node js (https://github.com/nijikokun/generate-schema). But i am using angularjs and html as front end technologies, Java and mongoDB as back end technologies.I want to load the node js code in angular js.like this

```
var GenerateSchema = require('generate-schema')
```

how?

Comment: try webpack, its great

Comment: check out expose loader: https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader

Comment: Thank you for your  answer.Correct me if i am wrong while using  Browserify. I downloaded project from https://github.com/nijikokun/generate-schema and  created bundle.js using Browserify. If i include the bundle.js file in angular project will it recognize require() from angular .js file.Is this correct way to do?

Comment: I've only used webpack, but you should be able to put the project in `window` with browserify too.  Then you just access as you would a normal script that you included in your html page.

Comment: Is there any way to generate json schema from json object in angularjs?